# I can't get multiple values out of MySQL using a select statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This is my code:

```
$bookresult = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT bookID 
                                   FROM order_items 
                                  WHERE orderID = '".$orders['orderID']."';");
```

The problem I have is that there are multiple bookIDs that are pulled out of MySQL. So when I do this:

```
$books = mysqli_fetch_array($bookresult);
```

There is no way for me to get all the bookIDs that should show when using that select statement, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Am I missing something, or do you not know how to work with arrays?

Comment: When I do
 '$books['bookID']'
I only get one of the bookIDs that were in MySQL. I probably am forgetting something really basic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop to go through all of the values.

You can view them by using the following php code.
(You can use mysql_fetch_array in place of mysql_fetch_assoc if you wish.

```
while ($books_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($bookresult)) {
  //output here.
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($books_row);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

The output there is great for debugging...replace it with what you think is best after you solve this problem. :)
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 5):

mysqli_fetch_array($bookresult) must be run multiple times until it returns null.  Just do a loop like so:

```
while ($book_result_row = mysqli_fetch_array($bookresult)) {
    // Do something with your $book_result_row
}
```